# android send and receive file through bluetooth

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

i wrote an app that **send**/ **receive** file through bluetooth but i want to set this app as a default app to send and receive files!

this is my code

**Listener**

```
public class ReceiverModeratorThread extends Thread{

    private final BluetoothServerSocket serverSocket;
    private final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    public ReceiverModeratorThread() {
        super();
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
        try {
            tmp = bluetoothAdapter
                    .listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(
                            bluetoothAdapter.getName(),
                            UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB")
                    );

        } catch (IOException e) { }

        serverSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.d("MyListener", "Run receiver Moderator");
        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
            Log.d("MyListener", "while");
            try {
                Log.d("MyListener", "start try");
                BluetoothSocket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                Log.d("MyListener", "Run create socket");

                Thread t = new getFileThread(socket);
                t.setDaemon(true);
                t.start();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("MyListener", "Run receiver Moderator Exception");
            }


        }
    }

}
```

i search alot but i can't find any way to set my app as a defualt app to send and receive file

what i have to do? am i use an special UUID?

**Explanation**
when a mobile device send a file to my mobile; my App get that file and work with it after that save when and where i want.

Comment: What do you mean by "default" ? Do you mean it should appear in the share list?

Comment: maybe you need to use default Android UUID? i search that for you but i can't find it. any one knows that?

Answer (score 0):

A 'default' send hook is done via Intents described in your manifest. You should add to your Activity the specific Intent filter for sending files.

(Receiving I don't know if it works the same way)

Comment: can you explain more? if you put a sample code i really thank you.